# Laravel Utilize ValidationException

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling, try-catch

I am using...

```
$validator  = Validator::make(...)
```

...to validate my input. However, instead of using that method, for API purposes, I would like to make use of Laravel's Validation Exception class.

Currently, I am trying:

```
// Model (Not Eloquent Model)
Validator::make(...) 

// Controller
try { $model->createUser(Request $request); }
catch(ValidationException $ex)
{
    return response()->json(['errors'=>$ex->errors()], 422);
}
```

However, the validation in the model does not appear to throw any validation exceptions. I can still get the errors by using `$validator->errors()`. Yet, that is still defeating my purpose.

I am trying to keep really clean controllers with only try and catch statements; therefore, keeping any and all logic and out of controllers.

How can I utilize the `ValidationException` to do just that?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what happens in your `$model->createUser(Request $request);`, but if you use the `Validator` facade then you'd have to process the validation yourself as in:

```
use Validator;

...

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // With a "Accept: application/json" header, this will format the errors
    // for you as the JSON response you have right now in your catch statement
    $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
}
```

On the other hand you might want to use the `validate()` method in your controller as it does all of the above for you:

```
$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Comment: Awesome, I was unaware of that. Thanks. I will do that instead, the validate method on the controller